# Problemas para mostrar en tabla texto de color rojo por diferencia de fechas

Tags: javascript, java, css, jsp, date

estoy intentando mostrar la diferencia de días que hay entre dos fechas de un préstamo, la de solicitud y la de devolución, así como mostrar con texto de color rojo, o bien con una celda de color rojo, el préstamo que ha sido devuelto fuera de un plazo determinado, en este caso 10 días.

Mi idea es usar un método al cual le pase las dos fechas, me calcule la diferencia en días y lo pueda mostrar en una tabla. Los datos de la solicitud y la devolución ya los tengo en una base de datos. En teoría el método funciona.

en el jsp importo la clase, construyo el objeto y lo empleo en la celda correspondiente, así lo he hecho antes para convertir las fechas en formato correcto y hacer que los null no aparezcan, he logrado todo menos cambiar el color.

Os paso el código del método que tengo en una clase dentro de un package llamado Utilidades.

```
package Utilidades;

import java.util.Date;

public class InformeRetraso {

    public String TiempoRetraso(Date fechaDevolucion, Date fechaSolicitud) {
        String resultado;

        if (fechaDevolucion == null) {
            resultado = "sin devolver";
        } else {
            long diferenciaEnms = fechaDevolucion.getTime() - fechaSolicitud.getTime();
            long dias = diferenciaEnms / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

            if (dias <= 10) {
                resultado = "devuelto en plazo";
            } else {
                resultado = "devuelto fuera de plazo";
                //resultado = Long.toString(dias);
            }

            //String resultado=dias.toString();
        }
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

y aquí la hoja JSP

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Prestamo"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOPrestamo"%>
<%@page import="Utilidades.FechaAFormato"%>
<%@page import="Utilidades.InformeRetraso"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="prestamo" class="Entidades.Prestamo" />
<jsp:setProperty name="prestamo" property="*"/>


<%
String message = "";
List<Prestamo> prestamos = null;
DAOPrestamo dao = new DAOPrestamo();
FechaAFormato fecha = new FechaAFormato();
InformeRetraso calculo = new InformeRetraso();
try {

    prestamos = dao.selectPrestamo();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.toString();

}

%>



<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>V2formListarPrestamo</title>
    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - PRESTAMOS</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Inicio</a></h2> 
                <h2><a href="V2HojaPrestamos.jsp">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form>
                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="status_initial" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else { %>

                <br/><br/>

                <table border="1">
                    <tr>

                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>DNI Usuario</th>
                        <th>ISBN Obra</th>
                        <th>Fecha Solicitud</th>
                        <th>Fecha Devolucion</th>
                        <th>Retraso</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!--creación de una tabla para mostrar todos los objetos prestamo-->
                    <%
                        for (int i = 0; i < prestamos.size(); i++) {%>
                    <tr>

                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getId()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getDNIusuario()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getISBNobra()%></td>
                        <td><%=fecha.FechaATexto(prestamos.get(i).getFechasolicitud())%></td>
                        <td><%=fecha.FechaATexto(prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion())%></td>
                        <td><%=calculo.TiempoRetraso(prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion(), prestamos.get(i).getFechasolicitud())%></td>

                    </tr>   

                    <%}%>
                </table>
                <%}%>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

La idea, que en la última columna que se crea se pase en la función los valores de solicitud y devolución, se resten y se muestren.

Así es como se ve ahora mismo, lo que busco lo expongo abajo.

[image: así es como se muestra ahora el listado]

Lo que quiero lograr es que , según el valor, se muestre el mensaje que muestro ahora,pero si la fecha de devolución es sin devolver sea en color amarillo, si es devuelto en plazo en color verde y fuera de plazo con un color de texto en rojo, por ejemplo.

Comment: Puede que para algunos casos fechaDevolucion y fechaSolicitud sean nulos, entonces al realizar el .getTime() de null, te lanza la excepción, veriifca que estos valores sean distintos a null antes de realizar la comparación.

Comment: Es correcto, ahora tengo que establecer como conyrolar esos null en fecha de devolucion, voy a ver como hacer, se agradecen sugerencias.

Comment: he añadido una modificación en el código, logro separar todo y dejar claro cuales están fuera de plazo, cuales no y cuales no se han devuelto, modifico la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arreglado, la manera era añadir Jquery para que las celdas con ciertos valores cambiaran a cierto color, añado el código.

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="Entidades.Prestamo"%>
<%@page import="DAO.DAOPrestamo"%>
<%@page import="Utilidades.FechaAFormato"%>
<%@page import="Utilidades.InformeRetraso"%>
<%@page import="Conexion.DBConnection"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<jsp:useBean id="prestamo" class="Entidades.Prestamo" />
<jsp:setProperty name="prestamo" property="*"/>

<%
String message = "";
List<Prestamo> prestamos = null;
DAOPrestamo dao = new DAOPrestamo();
FechaAFormato fecha = new FechaAFormato();
InformeRetraso calculo = new InformeRetraso();
try {
    prestamos = dao.selectPrestamo();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    message = ex.toString();
}
%>


<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>V2formListarPrestamo</title>

    <link href="../css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="titulo">
        <h1>BIBLIOTECA - PRESTAMOS</h1>
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="opciones">
                <h2><a href="../Menu.jsp">Inicio</a></h2> 
                <h2><a href="V2HojaPrestamos.jsp">Atras</a></h2> 
            </div>
            <form>
                <%if (!message.isEmpty()) {%>
                <input name="status_initial" type="text" style="width:400px" value="<%=message%>"/>
                <%} else { %>

                <br/><br/>
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $(function () {
                        $('#tabla1 td:last-child:contains(devuelto fuera de plazo)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'red');
                        //$('#tabla1 td:last-child:contains(sin devolver)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'yellow');
                        //$('#tabla1 td:last-child:contains(devuelto en plazo)').closest('tr').css('background-color', 'blue');
                    });

                </script>    

                <table id="tabla1" border="1">
                    <tr>

                        <th>id</th>
                        <th>DNI Usuario</th>
                        <th>ISBN Obra</th>
                        <th>Fecha Solicitud</th>
                        <th>Fecha Devolucion</th>
                        <th>Situación del préstamo</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!--creación de una tabla para mostrar todos los objetos prestamo-->
                    <%
                        for (int i = 0; i < prestamos.size(); i++) {%>


                    <tr>

                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getId()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getDNIusuario()%></td>
                        <td><%=prestamos.get(i).getISBNobra()%></td>
                        <td><%=fecha.FechaATexto(prestamos.get(i).getFechasolicitud())%></td>
                        <td><%=fecha.FechaATexto(prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion())%></td>
                        <td id="celda"><%=calculo.TiempoRetraso(prestamos.get(i).getFechadevolucion(), prestamos.get(i).getFechasolicitud())%></td>
                    </tr>   

                    <%}%> 

                </table>                       
                <%}%>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```